# Text field and send button disappear when running MyFirsApp

Tags: java, android, xml, button, textfield

I am trying to build my first android app (MyFirstApp) using the "Building Your First App" tutorial on the Android Developers website (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). I have reached the end of the "Starting Another Activity" portion of the tutorial, where I am meant to run the app, type  in some text and click the send button. When I run the app I get no errors, a few warnings and a blank screen with only the title of my app.How can I resolve this?

Below is my code so far:

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_messages"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_messages" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MyFirstApp</string>
    <string name="edit_messages">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

 </resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package my.first.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {        
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_messages);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

 }
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
 package my.first.app;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.os.Build;


 public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

        //Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

     // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

 }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                  container, false);
          return rootView;
    }
  }
}
```

fragment_display_message.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="my.first.app.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Add below code line after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in onCreate() Method of MainActivity Class, it will solve your problem.

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: But I seem to have encountered another problem. When I try to enter a message and click send, the app seems to crash. I get the message "Unfortunately, MyFirstApp has stopped."

Comment: Please Check your Logcat Details and put as a new question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `setContentView()` in MainActivity..

Define `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);` after savedInstance

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response. It really helped. :-)